# What to mention for editor if one isn't available for a book

Tags: bibtex

When using **Bibtex - InBook option**, what do write for the **ALTeditor** if one isn't available for a book.

The relevant fields are stated below. That means, I have to write something for the ALTeditor. I have two questions actually, for any book, where to locate the editor? In the event no editor is mentioned, what would I write for this field?

```
@InBook{•,
ALTauthor = {•},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {•},
chapter = {•},
publisher = {•},
year = {•},
OPTkey = {•},
OPTvolume = {•},
OPTnumber = {•},
OPTseries = {•},
OPTtype = {•},
OPTaddress = {•},
OPTedition = {•},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTpages = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
```

Comment: Could you make an example?

Comment: i removed the [editors] tag; that's for text editors, not bibliographic info.

Comment: @egreg: I have added example of fields.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz Sorry for not having been able to explain myself, but this is not the kind example I asked for: what's the real entry you need and what bibliography style are you using?

Comment: @egreg: I am actually new to Latex, so I would need lots of clarification. Basically, I am using  theapa style of bibliography.

Comment: If a book does not have editors, then you can safely remove the field. In the template you use (from `emacs`) `ALTauthor' and `ALTeditor` means  either use `author` or `editor`. So what you have to do is complete the field for which you have information, remove `ALT` and remove the other field (if I  remember correctly `emacs` would do that for you)

Comment: If it is a book of collected articles/essays, you are better off using `@InCollection` or `@InProceedings`.  The BibTeX mode of `emacs` expects for an `@InBook` entry, the entry itself has *either* an author *or* an editor --- which simply isn't true sometimes.  Thus `C-c C-c` ('Clean entry') will not work because you have filled both sides of an either/or. (You can work around this by deleting, say, the editor, validating the entry, then manually adding the editor.)   The other two entry types give you `author` (of the article/essay) and an `OPTeditor` (of the collection of articles/essays).